# pyspark - find max and min in json streamed data usign createDataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a set of json messages streamed by Kafka, each describing a website user. Using pyspark, I need to count the number of users per country per streaming window, and return the countries with the max and min number of users.

Here is an example of the streamed json messages:

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Barthel","last_name":"Kittel","email":"bkittel0@printfriendly.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"130.187.82.195","date":"06/05/2018","country":"France"}
```

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'ip_address', 'date', 'country']
schema =  StructType([
  StructField(field, StringType(), True) for field in fields
])

def parse(s, fields):
    try:
        d = json.loads(s[0])
        return [tuple(d.get(field) for field in fields)]
    except:
        return []

array_of_users = parsed.SQLContext.createDataFrame(parsed.flatMap(lambda s: parse(s, fields)), schema)

rdd = sc.parallelize(array_of_users)

# group by country and then substitute the list of messages for each country by its length, resulting into a rdd of (country, length) tuples
country_count = rdd.groupBy(lambda user: user['country']).mapValues(len)

# identify the min and max using as comparison key the second element of the (country, length) tuple
country_min = country_count.min(key = lambda grp: grp[1])
country_max = country_count.max(key = lambda grp: grp[1])
```

When I run it, I get the message

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6e6b83935bc3> in <module>()
     16         return []
     17 
---> 18 array_of_users = parsed.SQLContext.createDataFrame(parsed.flatMap(lambda s: parse(s, fields)), schema)
     19 
     20 rdd = sc.parallelize(array_of_users)

AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'SQLContext'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you getting a window of data?

Comment: `ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)` (using PySpark)

Comment: I'm not seeing that line, or where you defined `parsed` in your code...

Comment: Note: Kafka streaming 0.8 library is deprecated as of Spark 2.3.0, and it seems you have maybe followed this blog,  which is using these same variable names https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need to group the list of messages by country, then count the number of messages in each group and then select the groups with the min and max number of messages.

Out of my head, the code would be something like:

```
# assuming the array_of_users is your array of messages
rdd = sc.parallelize(array_of_users)

# group by country and then substitute the list of messages for each country by its length, resulting into a rdd of (country, length) tuples
country_count = rdd.groupBy(lambda user: user['country']).mapValues(len)

# identify the min and max using as comparison key the second element of the (country, length) tuple
country_min = country_count.min(key = lambda grp: grp[1])
country_max = country_count.max(key = lambda grp: grp[1])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint! As far as I understand, my messages are in `parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))`. How can I go from this to the `array_of_users` you suggest?

Comment: This may come in handy, take a look at the use of transform: https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/